# btrfs: why subvolid is different than value provided to mount?

Tags: btrfs

After executing:

```
sudo mount -o subvolid=0 /dev/sdc3 /mnt/temp
```

mount shows this:

```
/dev/sdc3 on /mnt/temp type btrfs (rw,relatime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/)
```

Why subvolid is 5 despite I specified 0 ?
I don't have any subvolume with this ID. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually from the [official BTRFS wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide), it's written that the toplevel subvolid is 5. The quote :

> The top-level subvolume (ID5) (which one can think of as the root of the filesystem) can be mounted, and the full filesystem structure will be seen at the mount point; alternatively any other subvolume can be mounted (with the mount options subvol or subvolid, for example subvol=subvol_a) and only anything below that subvolume (in the above example the subvolume subvol_b, it's contents, and file file_4) will be visible at the mount point

So you should either mount the filesystem without any subvol or subvolid option like this :

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc3 /mnt/temp
```

or explicitly specify the subvol of the top-level, which is 5 (not 0).

```
sudo mount -o subvolid=5 /dev/sdc3 /mnt/temp
```

In both cases you will end up with the top-level subvolume mounted.